# Ionic click event get element

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I have an `ion-grid` where I can have `x` rows with 11 columns:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="row" *ngFor="let row of grid">
      <ion-col class="col" col-1 *ngFor="let file_uri of row">
         <button ion-button class='buttoncell' ion-button (click)="editEntryValue($event)">{{file_uri}}</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

As you can see the cells of the table are buttons. In the `.ts` file I have the following:

```
editEntryValue(event: any){
    console.log(event);
}
```

So I get a `MouseEvent` object as event. But when a button is clicked, I need to know from which row (number) and which column (number) it has come from. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could add the index to both loops, and send it when clicking the button:

```
<ion-grid>
    <ion-row class="row" *ngFor="let row of grid; let rowIndex=index">
      <ion-col class="col" col-1 *ngFor="let file_uri of row; let colIndex=index">
         <button ion-button class='buttoncell' ion-button (click)="editEntryValue($event, rowIndex, colIndex)">{{file_uri}}</button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

And then:

```
editEntryValue(event: any, rowIndex: number, colIndex: number): void {
    console.log(`Row: ${rowIndex}`);
    console.log(`Col: ${colIndex}`);
}
```